# Too many results from 2 cte´s

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have 2 cte´s.
First cte D have this result:

```
ID   START_DATE    END_DATE
1    2013-12-30    2015-04-16
1    2017-01-16     null
```

Second cte C this:

```
ID   START_DATE    END_DATE
 1    2014-01-01  2015-04-16
 1    2017-01-16  2999-12-31
```

Now i join this 2 ctes

```
select 
   case when c.start_date = ('2014-01-01') then d.start_date
   else c.start_date
   end as first,
   case when d.end_date is null then c.end_date
   else d.end_date
   end as second
from D
inner join C on (d.vers_id = c.vers_id)
```

Result:

```
ID   FIRST        SECOND    
1    2017-01-16   2999-12-31     
1    2017-01-16   2015-04-16
1    2017-01-16   2015-04-16
1    2013-12-30   2015-04-16
```

My desired result is:

```
ID   FIRST        SECOND    
1    2017-01-16   2999-12-31 
1    2013-12-30   2015-04-16
```

Here I'm stuck, I don't know what to do to get just the 2 rows. I'm getting 4 rows with what I am trying.

Comment: You should explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need to take the dates into account:

```
select least(c.start_date, d.start_date) as first,
       coalesce(c.end_date, d.end_date) as second
from d inner join
     c
     on d.vers_id = c.vers_id and
        (c.start_date < d.end_date or d.end_date is null) and
        d.start_date < c.end_date;
```

This should at least produce the results you want for this data.